# python pandas-profiling problem with installation

Tags: python, pandas-profiling

I'm trying to install pandas-profiling on linux by comand `pip install pandas-profiling`.
Unfortunately I get error with marukpsafe module:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement markupsafe~=2.0.1 (from pandas-profiling) (from version 0.9,...,1.1.1).

I've installed version 1.1.1 of markupsafe so I don't understand this error.
Can You help me ?
Thanks